Join 2 tables using JPA Specifications
I have 2 Tables
public class Subscription {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;
    private Integer subscriptionTypeId;
    private Boolean active;
    private Long subscriberId;
}

public class SpecialSubscription {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Subscription.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "subscriptionId", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Subscription subscription;

    private String searchType;
    private Long refIfd;
}

I need to write a Specification that joins the 2 tables and fetches List where SpecialSubscription.searchType = specified input and SpecialSubscription.refId = specified input.
Something like this.
public static Specification<Subscription> bySearchTypeAndRefId(String searchType, Long refId) {
    return (root, query, builder) -> {
        Join<Subscription, SpecialSubscription> join =
            root.join(SpecialSubscription_.subscription.toString());
        return builder.and(builder.equal(join.get(SpecialSubscription_.searchType), searchType),
                builder.equal(join.get(SpecialSubscription_.normalizedRefId), refId)
        );
    };
}

This is the equivalent sql I would write if it were sql:
select s.* from subscriptions s, special_subscriptions ss where s.id = ss.subscription_id and ss.search_type = ? and ss.ref_id = ?;
Tried the code snippet mentioned in description but did not work.

And what does your code you've entered give you? Why are you calling NewsletterSubscription_.subscription.toString() in there instead of just NewsletterSubscription_.subscription? Youve made it overly difficult to read showing us Subscription and SpecialSubscription but then using EmailSubscription and NewsletterSubscription in the query. Maybe simplify it in a test case and show us that. I would guess your issue is that you are querying on Subscriptions but need to somehow access the SpecialSubscription that reference subscriptions for your filter - is that correct?

Sorry for that. I just updated the code snippet with SpecialSubscription and Subscription.

Also yes, my issue is that Subscription entity does not have reference of SpecialSubscription in it. This is what I would do if it were sql:
select s.* from subscriptions s, special_subscriptions ss where s.id = ss.subscription_id and ss.search_type = ? and ss.ref_id = ?;

or JPQL " select s from SpecialSubscription ss join ss.subscription s where ss.searchType = :searchType and ss.refIfd = :refId". It works out to be the same in Criteria api - you need to start from SpecialSubscription as the root instead of Subscription.  If you can't, you can still go the other way: "select s from Subscription s join SpecialSubscription ss on ss.subscription = s where ss.searchType = :searchType and ss.refIfd = :refId". CriteriaApi does not include the same capability - you would need to have two from clauses then link them.


my issue is that Subscription entity does not have reference of SpecialSubscription in it.

your actual issue is you assuming that traversing associations is the only way to construct joins in Criteria API.
public static Specification<Subscription> bySearchTypeAndRefId(String searchType, Long refId) {
    return (root, query, builder) -> {
        Root<SpecialSubscription> ss = query.from(SpecialSubscription.class);
        return builder.and(
            builder.equal(ss.get(SpecialSubscription_.subscription), root),
            builder.equal(ss.get(SpecialSubscription_.searchType), searchType),          
            builder.equal(ss.get(SpecialSubscription_.normalizedRefId), refId)
        );
    };
}


Thanks that worked
